# Lua XML extract from pattern

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

An application is sending my script an Stream like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <aRootChildNode>
    <anotherChildNode>
     <?xml version="1.0">
     <TheNodeImLookingFor>
       ... content ...
     </TheNodeImLookingFor>
    </anotherChildNode>
   </aRootChildNode>
</root>
```

I want to extract the `TheNodeImLookingFor` section.
So far, got:

```
data = string.match(Stream, "^.+\<TheNodeImLookingFor\>.+\<\/TheNodeImLookingFor\>.+$")
```

Pattern is recognized in the Stream, but it doesn't extract the node and its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's not a good idea to use pattern matching (either Lua pattern or regex) to extract XML. Use a XML parser.

For this problem, you don't need to escape `\` or `<`(even if you do, Lua pattern uses `%` to escape magic characters). And use brackets to get the node and its content:

```
data = string.match(Stream, "^.+(<TheNodeImLookingFor>.+</TheNodeImLookingFor>).+$")
```

Or to get only the content:

```
data = string.match(Stream, "^.+<TheNodeImLookingFor>(.+)</TheNodeImLookingFor>.+$")
```

Comment: Nevermind, I found another post which explains more or less how to extract the node and its content. I've done the following: `for att, cont in data:gmatch'<Request.+>.+</Request>' do {whatever} end`